# Line is skipping in BIRT Viewer when combining two dataset

Tags: eclipse, birt

When we have extremely large 'PODESCOFGOODS' data. The report is populating with skipped line as below.

[image]

[image]

We have removed 'DESCOFGOODS' and keep only ‘PODESCOFGOODS’ dataset in JavaScript expression and ran the report it was working as expected. But when we have two dataset and extreme large data then, the report is failed.

[image]

[image]

Note: The issues occurred only with web viewer. The other format (i.e. PDF, word, etc.) was working as expected though have large data’s.

Comment: Don't know, but you could simplify your JS code: Instead of testing for != null and != "", you could just use if (dataSetRow["test1"]). A string expression is "true" if it is defined, not null and not empty. Furthermore the semicolon at the end should be removed.

Comment: And please improve your question. It is not clear what you mean.

Comment: improved the question. please help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Sorry. Though I think I understand the problem now (the output is truncated), I have no idea what might cause the issue. Especially why this happens only with the HTML emitter.